# How can I get Windows Error Report (WER) reports for a win32 exe from Microsoft in 2019

Tags: windows, windows-error-reporting, winqual

Because the documentation is hopelessly out of date (directing you to the non-existent Winqual or sysdev.microsoft.com)

I can see that my exe is sending these reports from the control panel, but I cannot find anywhere to register to receive them on Windows Dev Center. Note that this is NOT a UWP app.

The MetadataExchange tool that used to connect to it seems to have vanished (it was hosted on sysdev.microsoft.com).

So, Microsoft has the WER reports for my app users. In the year 2019 how can I get them?

Comment: It used to be possible to subscribe to Microsoft's WER service. Afaik that program was discontinued quite a while ago. Only the dashboard for UWP apps remains. Generating your own and not relying on Microsoft is still the norm, like it always was, SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and MiniDumpWriteDump() are the workhorse api functions.  Easy to google to find code.

Comment: And yet these results still get sent to Microsoft, but apparently with no way for the original developer to read them? What are they doing with them?

Comment: When you create your own there is no point in letting it continue into WER, you'd simply terminate the app.  There is a way to configure WER to generate local minidumps, ask at superuser.com if [this](https://superuser.com/questions/553140/where-does-windows-8-store-user-mode-crash-minidumps) doesn't help.  Afaik Microsoft mostly uses them to identify emerging OS compatibility problems.